# Can an oven be kashered without a torch soon after use?

Tags: halacha, kashering-kosherization

I have been told that an oven may be kashered without the use of a torch for Libum even if it has not had 24 hrs at rest! Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  I've edited the title of your question to be a little more descriptive.  I wasn't sure which factor you think is primary, if either (without a torch, or within 24 hours).  Please feel free to edit further.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You might be thinking of a self cleaning oven. The self cleaning cycle is sufficient to kasher it. Non self cleaning ovens may be kashered by running at the highest setting for a set period of time.

For example

[How do I kosher an oven?](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/623729/jewish/How-do-I-kosher-an-oven.htm)

> If your oven is of the self-cleaning variety, koshering it is fairly simple. All you need to do is self-clean it. If you need to kosher the oven racks too, just leave them in the oven while it self-cleans.

[THE STAR-K PESACH KITCHEN](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-passover-kashering.htm)

> **The Oven**
>   In a conventional oven, whether gas or electric, an oven
>   cleaner may be necessary to remove baked-on grease. Be sure to check
>   hidden areas, including corners, door edges, the area behind the flame
>   burners, and the grooves of the rack shelves. If a caustic type of
>   oven cleaner (such as Easy-Off) was used to clean the oven, and some
>   stubborn spots remained after a second application with similar
>   results, the remaining spots may be disregarded. Once the oven and
>   racks have been cleaned, they may be kashered by libbun kal. The
>   requirement of libbun kal is satisfied by turning the oven to broil or
>   the highest setting for forty minutes. In a gas oven, the broil
>   setting will allow the flame to burn continuously. In a conventional
>   electric oven, the highest setting (550°F) kashers the oven. Only
>   libbun kal is required for the oven racks since it is usual to cook
>   food in a pan and not directly on the racks themselves.
>
> In a continuous cleaning oven, one cannot assume that such an oven is
>   clean because the manufacturer claims it to be continuously clean. A
>   visual inspection is required. Since caustic or abrasive oven
>   cleaners, e.g. Easy Off, cannot be used without destroying the
>   continuous clean properties of the oven, a non-abrasive and
>   non-caustic cleaner must be used to clean the oven. Grease spots will
>   usually disappear if the top layer of grease is cleaned with Fantastik
>   and a nylon brush. Then the oven should be turned on to 450°F for an
>   hour, so that the continuous clean mechanism can work. If the spots do
>   not disappear, the oven should be left on for a few hours to allow the
>   continuous clean mechanism to deep clean, or else the spots should be
>   removed with oven cleaner or steel wool. If the spots are dark and
>   crumble when scratched they can be disregarded. In all of the above
>   cases, the oven should then be kashered by turning it to the 550°F
>   setting for forty minutes.
>
> In a self-cleaning oven; before using the self clean cycle, one should
>   clean the inside face of the oven door, as well as the opposing outer
>   rim of the oven outside the gasket, since these areas are not
>   necessarily cleaned during the cycle. Easy Off manufactures one
>   product that is safe for self-cleaning ovens. One should ensure the
>   gasket itself is clean on the area outside the oven seal. (Note: The
>   gasket is sensitive to abrasion). The self-cleaning cycle will then
>   clean and kasher the oven simultaneously. Caution: There is a
>   potential risk of fire during the self-cleaning process, especially if
>   there is a great collection on the bottom of the oven. It is
>   recommended to apply Easy Off that is made especially for self-clean
>   ovens to lift and remove the grease. The oven should not be left
>   unattended while in the self-cleaning mode. Due to reports of fires,
>   one should not leave other operating heating appliances i.e. dryers,
>   toasters, coffee makers, toaster ovens, microwave ovens, or
>   dishwashers unattended. In fact, toasters and toaster ovens should be
>   unplugged (by pulling on the plug and not the cord) when not in use.
>
> Most oven manufacturers instruct the consumer to remove the oven racks
>   before self cleaning, so they will not discolor. However, one may self
>   clean the oven with the racks inside, even though they might discolor.
>   After the self clean cycle use a little oil on the side of the racks
>   to easily slide them in and out of the oven. Also, there are some
>   manufacturers that require removal of the racks before the self clean
>   cycle can start. In this case, one should take the racks out, clean
>   them very well, and then put them in the oven at the highest
>   temperature (usually 550°F) for 45 minutes. This procedure kashers
>   them.
>
> Some ovens come with a convection feature. This feature allows for
>   more uniform heat distribution by using a fan to circulate the heat.
>   If the convection oven has the self-cleaning feature, it will be
>   sufficient to kasher the fan as well. If there is no self-cleaning
>   feature, the entire oven including the fan, while it is circulating
>   must be sprayed with a caustic cleaner and cleaned well. The oven
>   should then be kashered by turning it on to the 550°F setting for
>   forty minutes.

[OU statement](http://oukosher.org/passover/articles/modern-kitchen/)

> SELF-CLEAN OVENS
>   LIBUN   >
>   Remove any visible food. Complete self-cleaning
>   cycle with racks in place.
>
> NON SELF-CLEANING OVEN   >
>   LIBUN
>   Clean all surfaces (walls, floor, doors
>   and racks) thoroughly with a caustic cleanser (e.g., Easy Off). Pay
>   special attention to thermostat, oven window, and edges of the oven
>   chamber. Black discoloration that is flush with the metal need not be
>   removed. Oven should not be used for 24 hours. Place racks in the oven
>   and turn the oven to broil (highest heat) for 90 minutes. A broiler
>   pan that comes in direct contact with food should not be used.Note:
>   The method of kashering described above is based on the ruling of Rav
>   Aharon Kotler zt’l. However, Rav Moshe Feinstein zt’l ruled that the
>   oven must either be kashered with a blow torch, or an insert should be
>   placed in the oven. Consult your rabbi for guidance.

Comment: Self cleaning an oven is using torch-libbun. The question was seeking something else.

Comment: @DoubleAA while it may work through the same halachic principles, running a self-clean cycle is not using a torch.

Comment: Something to concider. The darkei tshuva bring a disagreement if one is allowed to kasher an oven from milk to meat and vice versa at all. It depends if you compare this to kashering with hagaala which the achronim all accepted from the Magen Avraham not to do. Most modern day poskim have an opinion on this as well and as the saying goes CYLOR.

Comment: @user6591 NOT all achronim accepted that Magen Avraham. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7501/759

Comment: @Double you are right. I should have said poskim not achronim. I haven't met one who doesn't paskin like that. Have you?

Comment: @user6591 See my comment there. I don't know anyone who thinks it's good policy but I have met people who don't think there is any formal Gezera. Hanach lahem liyisrael! They're probably better off this way.

Comment: @Double i would definitely advocate the hanach lahem but in this particular case this is usually the one 'halacha' that people know about bassar bichalav. Basic shulchan aruch is ignored and left to be learnt when one becomes a 'rabbi', but this? This is the the holy taphel who's worth far outweighs all the ikarim. (Vent over) So it's hard to be meikel on something like that in my eyes. But i personally DO kasher many oven in light of all this, because not everyone thinks it does or should apply. I just meant CYLOR.