# Status of porcelain plates

Tags: kashrut-kosher, keilim

What is the status of porcelain dishes that have not been used for over a year?

Can one change their designation from one (meat) to the other (dairy) or vice versa?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) B. MY is not for personalized questions so I allowed myself to edit your question in a more general way. Please make sure to ask a rav for specific questions as details will sometimes change the answer. Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 2):

You do not say if the dishes are kosher to start with. Porcelain has a special status as it is earthenware covered by a thin glass layer. That makes it impossible to kasher.

R David Rosenfeld at aish.com [writes](http://www.aish.com/atr/China-Dishes-Porcelain.html)

> In general the practice is not to kasher them. However, in cases
>   involving great loss, one may wait 12 months, kasher them in boiling
>   water 3 times, and then use them (Igrot Moshe Y.D. I 43)

yeshiva.co writes something very similar [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=5479) with more sources [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=6348).

**If the dishes were kosher to start with**, [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/66834/11501) brings sources re switching from dairy to meat and vice versa.

**Please** [ask a rav](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) as the interdiction of meat and milk is serious and you should not make halachic decisions based on what strangers write on the Internet.